# Only variable to be assigned by reference for $model and $modelproduct

Tags: php, joomla

For this code, its stating that only variable to be assigned by reference for `$model` and `$modelproduct`. I tried to look at some other example but could not make out of it.

Can any help on same?

```
public function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $app  = JFactory::getApplication();
        $user = JFactory::getUser();    
        // Push a model into the view
        $model          = &$this->getModel();
        $modelProduct   = &$this->getModel( 'pages' );
        $MSG="";
        $this->assignRef('MSG'  , $MSG);
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
```

Comment: `$model = &$this->getModel();` - you simply can not assign the result of a function / method call via reference. A reference needs to point to a specific location in memory - but only a variable provides that, the return value of a function call is not _“in”_ memory that way.

Comment: So what's the solution.

Comment: To assign the method call return value to a variable first - then you can assign a reference to that variable to something else. (Whether that is actually “the solution” here, of course depends on what actually needs to be achieved - but you did not explain that one bit so far, so we don’t know if what you are trying to do needs to use references in the first place.)

Comment: @Ruckika why not ask your Joomla question at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `&$this` in your code. It means that the result of the function should point to a specific location in memory and that could not be.

I cannot understand why you would like to do that but if think it is a bad understanding of reference. My solution is to remove & as it is unuseful in that case.